# jQuery div page slider off the screen, without a horizontal browser scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, slider

I'm looking for a jQuery div slider plugin that slides horizontal off the page, displaying more divs the larger the browser window is open. I like the jQuery Coda Slider... just need it to be full page, not hide the overflow, and not display the horizontal browser scrollbar.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATED:**
Below is an example of what I'm trying to get. Basically, it's two steps. The css and the js. The first step, the css, I'm looking to get a horizontal div page scroll without a fixed height. The second step, the js, I'm looking to get the divs to slide like the jQuery Coda Slider.

[image]

Comment: Slide off the page, not hide overflow, *and* not display horizontal scrollbar? I can't imagine how that would work. Why not hide overflow?

Comment: Imagine a margin left layout that is 700px wide and the user's browser is open to 1000px wide. The next div in the slider will partly appear in the browser, though it will be opaque and selectable allowing the slideshow to progress that way. If the user re-adjusts their browser window... more or less of the next slide will show. (The previous slide doesn't display.) It's pretty specific, I know, but wondering if there is something similar out there that I can start from. (I'll accept the best response, I promise.)

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know if I completely understand. Some code would be nice.

Anyway it sounds like you want the edge of the browser display to cut off whatever part of the next slide that is off the page.

If that's right, just set overflow-x to hidden on your `body` tag, or whatever container tag you're using that is the same width as the window.

(Except for some reason, you don't want hidden.)

```
           // If your content is in a container that is sized to the width
body {     //    of the body, then use that instead.
    clip: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** (with info from re-post)

style:

```
body {
            clip: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

     /* Positioning *
        #container { width: 2500px; }
        .block { float: left; }

        /* Styling */
        .block img { padding: 5px; }​
```

html:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="block"><img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/1zp2poz.gif"></div>
    <div class="block"><img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/1zp2poz.gif"></div>
    <div class="block"><img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/1zp2poz.gif"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This didn't work, please see my updated post above with graphic.

Comment: Do you know the width of the `div` elements? And are they floated left? You will need to make sure the width of the gray container is greater than the combined width of your `div` elements.

Comment: I reposted the question with an html example and a clearer explanation of the problem, please check it out if you have time. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851126/css-horizontal-scrolling-overflow-with-jquery-slider

Comment: I'll answer over here, since re-posts are generally not recommended on stackoverflow.