# jQuery horizontal slider with all images visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I'm looking for a jQuery slider plugin allowing me to do exactly that:

http://www.saslondon.com/what-we-do/digital-communications/bba-aviation.aspx

If found this thread: [CSS horizontal scrolling overflow with jQuery slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851126/css-horizontal-scrolling-overflow-with-jquery-slider) but the link is dead.

[image]

Do you know of any jQuery plugins that would allow me to do that with few modifications?
Otherwise, I'll try to do it myself...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need buttons? or mousemove? or? And if you need buttons... where do you want them?

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to do by yourself... `overflow: hidden;` and `animate()` is all you need.

Comment: I agree, it's not hard to do, but if it's been done well already... When I look at the code of the sas london plugin, there's definitely a bit more to it than just animate(). Roxon: dont care where the buttons are, should be easy to change with just some css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I created a gallery like the one you need (but a bit advanced)!

### [WORKING GALLERY](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/tMxp5/1/)

- with auto-slide support
- with window live-resize support
- looks for images completely visible!
- buttons appear on HOVER
- hover = STOP auto slide
- Set .box height/width = gallery auto resize.

---

The bonuses for the first gallery is that it gets the number of images 'in view' without the need to show them again on the next slide.

But if you want the gallery do EXACTLY what does the gallery you provided in your link
(slide one - by - one DIV) than here is another demo:

### [GALLERY 2](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/tMxp5/3/)

- added slide counter
- NO auto-slide
- NO buttons hide

Comment: Thanks ;) I'm going to rewrite this stuff in the form of a jquery plugin, but I'll use this as a basis.

Comment: you're welcome. Here is a tut. to get the same/similar gallery. It's the easiest way to build a gallery for any porpouses with few modifications. http://www.roxon.in/scripts/tutorials/NavGallery_jQuery_Tutorial_01/ P.S. I already have a plugin, but it still needs a few fixes to add more flexibility on the gallery class nomenclatures.

Comment: @Robin Hey, have you done the rewrite into the jquery plugin? It would be very helpful for me